# Getting percentages of counts in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am building an SQL Server query that gets the number of leads that were generated from a certain sources by month.  This is the query that tells me the monthly count.  But I want to add a column that shows what those leads are for that month as a total of all leads for that month.  I'm not clear on how to do this.  Any help?

```
SELECT FORMAT([ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08].[Created Date]
    , 'yyyy-MM') AS 'YYYY-MM'
    , 'Kiosk-Mall' AS 'Lead Source'
    , COUNT(*) AS 'Monthly Total From That Lead Source'
FROM [ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08] 
WHERE [ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08].[Lead Source] =
    'Kiosk-Mall'
GROUP BY FORMAT([ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08].[Created Date], 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY FORMAT([ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08].[Created Date], 'yyyy-MM');
```

Comment: *[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08]* Now I saw everything...

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation -- basically moving the `WHERE` condition to a `CASE` expressions in the argument to an aggregation function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(l.[Created Date], 'yyyy-MM') AS YYYYMM,
       'Kiosk-Mall' AS Lead_Source,
       SUM(CASE WHEN l.[Lead Source] = 'Kiosk-Mall' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Monthly Total From That Lead Source],
       AVG(CASE WHEN l.[Lead Source] = 'Kiosk-Mall' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS proportion_of_total
FROM [ProspectData].[dbo].[Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08] l
GROUP BY FORMAT(l.[Created Date], 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY YYYYMM
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- It is better to choose column aliases that do not need to be escaped (i.e. no spaces, no punctuation).

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
Invalid object name 'ProspectData.dbo.Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08'.

Comment: Without all of the brackets protecting that less-than-stellar table name, that error becomes a higher risk. Are all of those brackets in place in your test of Gordon's solution?

Comment: Can you query ProspectData directly, dropping the '[ProspectData].[dbo].' from the WHERE clause, and let us know if you still get the error? You'll still have to keep the table name [Real Estate.KPC.Leads.2018-08-08] in brackets